# Django - bulk data import: records not saved

Tags: python, django

Need to import data from CSV files into a Django app. Here's how a model looks like:

```
class MDfile(models.Model):
  file_name =  models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False)
  line = models.IntegerField()
  mkt_type = models.CharField(max_length=7, editable=False)
  # ...... etc.
  yearly_lo_price1 = models.CharField(max_length=9, editable=False)
```

And the method that gets invoked in the handler is straightforward:

```
def impMDfile(self, fileType, fullpath, filename):

    try:
        lines=1
        obj = MDfile()
        fromFile = open(fullpath)
        for eachLine in fromFile:
            fieldsInLine = eachLine.split(",")
            print fieldsInLine

            obj.file_name = filename
            obj.line = lines
            obj.mkt_type = fieldsInLine[0].strip()
            # ...... etc.
            obj.yearly_lo_price1 = fieldsInLine[12].strip()

            obj.save()
            lines+=1
    except BaseException as e:
        logging.info('\terror importing %s line %d : %s' % (fullpath, lines, e.__str__()))
    else:
        logging.info("\timported %s, %d lines" % (fullpath, lines))
```

The problem: Just a few random records are getting inserted into the db, whereas it prints all the lines to terminal when running, and the line counts are correct. The files have about 1.5 - 2.5k lines. Checked the table with psql too.

Using Django 1.7.1 in a Virtualenv; PostgreSQL database; Ubuntu 12.04. I'm not too great with Python; and just started off with Django. Any help/pointers appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention: this app is registered in settings.py, and is invoked as `python manage.py ftpimport`

Comment: It looks like you're importing a CSV. You might want to check out Python's csv library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create `obj = MDfile()` outside of the for loop, and then save it many times inside the loop. *Only the first save actually creates a new database record*. After that, each time it is saved, the record is updated.

Moving that line into the for loop is a quick fix.

If execution is too slow, a better way would be not to call `.save()` at all but to build a list of unsaved `MDfile` instances, and then to call `MDfile.objects.bulk_create(instances)` to create them all in one big query.